# Why would apt install an i386 dependency for an amd64 package?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wine, apt

I have a Compaq laptop with an Intel T2370 CPU, which is 64-bit.  Most of my applications are installed from the amd64 packages.  I installed WINE1.4 yesterday using Software Manager in Linux Mint 13 64-bit w/MATE.  Software Manager installed the following packages:

- wine1.4
- wine1.4-amd64
- wine-gecko1.4:i386

There is a wine-gecko1.4:amd64 in the repository.  Why would Software Manager install the i386 front end when an amd64 version is available?

Comment: syntax error in my question: Every reference to AMD64 should be amd64. Habit caused me to capitalize the acronym.  Oh, and I don't need the 64-bit memory addressing.  I have 4GB RAM.

Comment: The answer is obvious the process you are running is 32-bit.  BGoth 32-bit and 64-bit packages of `Wine` was installed because that is how the Software Manager is designed.  The solution is to install it without using the manager.

Comment: Only the 64-bit package of Wine was installed.  "wine1.4-i386" exists in the repositories as well, but was not installed.  I definitely got a mix, not both.

Comment: I uninstalled all WINE related packages then used apt-get to install, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I checked, the amd64 build of Wine ran 64-bit Windows binaries, while the i386 build ran 32-bit Windows binaries. Since the vast majority of Windows programs are still 32-bit (even today!) you do want the capability to run them.